# Is it possible to return Flow<List<Long>> after Room insert?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

Is it possible to return `Flow<List<Long>>` after `Room` insert?

Something like this:

```
@Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
suspend fun insert( notesModel: List<NotesModel>): Flow<List<Long>>
```

When I do it I get an exception:

> error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't. The return type of `@Insert` annotated functions could be `Unit`, `Long`, `List<Long>`, or `Array<Long>`.

Only `@Query` annotated functions are able to return observable objects like `LivaData`, `Flow`, `Single`, `Flowable`, *etc*. Because the `@Query` functions are designed to be able to reflect changes on db.

Here is a quote from [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert):

> If the @Insert method receives only 1 parameter, it can return a long, which is the new rowId for the inserted item. If the parameter is an array or a collection, it should return long[] or List instead.